# FragmentTabHost does not have the nested fragments in onTabChanged, why? How can I do?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-tab-host

I'm doing a small app with FragmentTabHost and two nested fragments. I need update the data of nested fragments from the fragment that contains the FragmentTabHost but for any reason I don't have the second fragment (second tab) when I do click in its tab then I get a null pointer exception.

Here it is a test of my code:

TabsTransactionFragment.java, this is the Fragment that contain the FragmentTabHost

```
    public class TabsTransactionFragment extends Fragment implements 
    OnTabChangeListener{

private static final String TAB_ONE_TAG = "ONE";
private static final String TAB_TWO_TAG = "TW0";

private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
private ArrayList<Integer> mData;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mData = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        mData.add(i);
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs_transations,
            container, false);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) view.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(),
            android.R.id.tabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_ONE_TAG).setIndicator(
                    "ODD"),
                    ListDataFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_TWO_TAG).setIndicator(
                    "EVEN"),
                    ListDataFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

    return mTabHost;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    mTabHost = null;
}

private void updateDataChildFragments(String tabName) {

    if (mData != null) {
        ListDataFragment listOneFragment = 
                (ListDataFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAB_ONE_TAG);

        ListDataFragment listTwoFragment = 
                (ListDataFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAB_TWO_TAG);

        if (tabName.equalsIgnoreCase(TAB_ONE_TAG)) {

            ArrayList<Integer> odds = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for (int i=0; i<mData.size(); i++) {
                if (mData.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
                    odds.add(mData.get(i));
                }
            }


            listOneFragment.updateData(odds);
        } else {
            ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for (int i=0; i<mData.size(); i++) {
                if (mData.get(i) % 2 != 0) {
                    even.add(mData.get(i));
                }
            }

            // Fragment two is null then crash...
            listTwoFragment.updateData(even);
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabName) {

    updateDataChildFragments(tabName);

}
```

}

Each tab contains a simple ListFragment like this:

```
public class ListDataFragment extends ListFragment {


private ArrayAdapter<Integer> mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);
}

public void updateData(ArrayList<Integer> data) {

    mAdapter.addAll(data);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

}

And layout fragment_tabs_transations.xml is the structure of android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost with a linearLayout, TabWidget and FrameLayout.

I have tried many things and ways but I haven't got to pass data to the second fragment once I do click... I have tried to created first both fragment and add to FragmentTabHost but I didn't get neither...

I think the problem it is the second fragment it is attached to FragmentTabHost after onTagChanged and that is because I can not find it... But I don't understand this behaviour... :S.

Anybody can help me? Or know any solution to pass data to second Fragment before do click in its tab?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Is it enough for you to pass the arguments once and for all in the bundle when you call addTab (instead of null in the last argument). Or you really need to update the data each time you switch back and again on the tab?

Comment: I need to update the data sometimes when I switch the tab and I can not pass the data like arguments in addTab because data is coming from asynctask then when I added the tabs I didn't have any data yet. The problem is only when you do click the first time because it is not attached or something like that, after this I could use this code.

Comment: In this case, I'm used to reload data in each fragment of the TabHost, who auto-manage itself (therefore the fragment does not care where it is, but just fetch what it needs). Thanks to cache, the data will not be loaded twice